# How to focus(), as in having a blinking caret on a div that has been given the attribute contentEditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How to `focus()`, as in having a blinking caret on a div that has been given the attribute `contentEditable`?

What I have so far is:

```
$("#q_edit_field_wrap")
 .attr("contentEditable", true)
 .focus();
```

As is, I have to actually click on the div first.

Comment: Works for me just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/wZ8hh/ Could some other code be inferring?

Comment: inferring = interfering* inferring code would be...scary?

Comment: @Detect, your example works for me in IE, FF and Chrome.